# Can a 403 error ever be client side?

Tags: apache, browsers, 403-forbidden

I've got a well-established web application. It's working for lots of people with a variety of browsers and platforms. But, there's this one guy...

He's getting a "403 Forbidden" on his side, I've even seen screen shots.  But, I'm not logging anything in Apache or Tomcat that seems to indicate that he's actually been denied. I know he's authenticating because I see it explicitly. This, combined with the fact that he's the only broken user makes me wonder.

Can a browser (IE in this case) ever decide on its own to throw a 403 that's not actually generated by the server?

P.S.: I don't have rep to create '403' tag, but it's probably appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

It could be generated by a proxy server between the client and your server. Check the error message.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions are to:

1. clear the users DNS cache
2. disable any proxy settings
3. check their hosts file for any references to `127.0.0.1`.

It's possible that the user has a web server enabled on the local machine and is hitting that instead.